# Stop fixed position at footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, fixed

I'm looking for a solution to the popular issue of stopping a fixed object at the footer of the page.

I basically have a fixed "share" box in the bottom left corner of the screen and I don't want it to scroll over the footer, so I need it to stop about `10px` above the footer.

I've looked at other questions here as well as others. The closest/most simple demo I could find is http://jsfiddle.net/bryanjamesross/VtPcm/ but I couldn't get it to work with my situation.

Here's the html for the share box:

```
    <div id="social-float">
        <div class="sf-twitter">
            ...
        </div>

        <div class="sf-facebook">
            ...
        </div>

        <div class="sf-plusone">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
```

...and the CSS:

```
#social-float{
position: fixed;
bottom: 10px;
left: 10px;
width: 55px;
padding: 10px 5px;
text-align: center;
background-color: #fff;
border: 5px solid #ccd0d5;
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
-moz-border-radius: 2px;
border-radius: 2px;
display: none;
}
```

The footer is `#footer` and it doesn't have a fixed height, if that makes any difference.

If someone could assist me in creating a simple jQuery solution for this, I'd much appreciate it!

Comment: What is different in the Fiddle from what you need?

Comment: The sidebar in the fiddle isn't fixed relative to the browser window. I don't know, it might be exactly the same concept, but I toyed around with it and I just couldn't get it to work with my scenario. I need the box to be in the bottom left corner of the window until it reaches the footer, where it will then scroll with the page.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Kkv7X)

first, check its offset every time you scroll the page

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    checkOffset();
});
```

and make its position absolute if it has been downed under 10px before the footer.

```
function checkOffset() {
    if($('#social-float').offset().top + $('#social-float').height() 
                                           >= $('#footer').offset().top - 10)
        $('#social-float').css('position', 'absolute');
    if($(document).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight < $('#footer').offset().top)
        $('#social-float').css('position', 'fixed'); // restore when you scroll up
}
```

notice that `#social-float`'s parent should be sibling of the footer

```
<div class="social-float-parent">
    <div id="social-float">
        something...
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
</div>
```

good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Now the box just flickers when it scrolls over the footer. Is there something I need to change in the CSS?

Comment: oh sorry, it's because the position style keep toggled since it fixed. try to change the operator '>' with '>='

Comment: Still flickers :( Here's a screencast of what's going on, if that'll help: http://youtu.be/aNnTARjYPOc

Comment: it seems like parent of your floating div contains footer... i made jsfiddle for you and checked my answer. it sticked well but it wasn't restored when i scroll up. so i added some code to resolve it. this is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kkv7X/ and I'll edit my answer again :)

Comment: @user984008 if you have same problem after you change your code like my fiddle, let me show your markup and css. then i think i can fix the bug.

Comment: I got it to work, thanks! I really appreciate your help and quick, helpful responses :D

Comment: Do you know Bootstrap implementation of that, someone?

Answer (score 27):

I've just solved this problem on a site I'm working on, and thought I would share it in the hope it helps someone.

My solution takes the distance from the footer to the top of the page - if the user has scrolled further than this, it pulls the sidebar back up with a negative margin.

```
$(window).scroll(() => { 
  // Distance from top of document to top of footer.
  topOfFooter = $('#footer').position().top;
  // Distance user has scrolled from top, adjusted to take in height of sidebar (570 pixels inc. padding).
  scrollDistanceFromTopOfDoc = $(document).scrollTop() + 570;
  // Difference between the two.
  scrollDistanceFromTopOfFooter = scrollDistanceFromTopOfDoc - topOfFooter;

  // If user has scrolled further than footer,
  // pull sidebar up using a negative margin.
  if (scrollDistanceFromTopOfDoc > topOfFooter) {
    $('#cart').css('margin-top',  0 - scrollDistanceFromTopOfFooter);
  } else  {
    $('#cart').css('margin-top', 0);
  }
});
```

Comment: This worked brilliantly. Top answer was a no go because my sidebars parent wasn't a sibling of the footer div. This answer is less fussy about the stack order of divs.

Comment: Brilliant answer. It helped with my scrollspy which overlaps footer when I scroll down. Thanks a lot sir..

Comment: Awesome answer! Reaaally easy to do (the previous JS solution are a bit scary when you don't know a lot ><" ). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Works perfectly.

Comment: Great solution! I also pulled this code into its own function and called it on scroll() as well as $(window).resize(), to account for the condition when they resize their browser window (which doesn't always call scroll() but may change the sizes enough to cause overlap)

Comment: Nice solution, but my footer height changes responsively.. how could I account for that?

Answer (score 20):

Here is the @Sang solution but without Jquery.

```js
var socialFloat = document.querySelector('#social-float');
var footer = document.querySelector('#footer');

function checkOffset() {
  function getRectTop(el){
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    return rect.top;
  }
  
  if((getRectTop(socialFloat) + document.body.scrollTop) + socialFloat.offsetHeight >= (getRectTop(footer) + document.body.scrollTop) - 10)
    socialFloat.style.position = 'absolute';
  if(document.body.scrollTop + window.innerHeight < (getRectTop(footer) + document.body.scrollTop))
    socialFloat.style.position = 'fixed'; // restore when you scroll up
  
  socialFloat.innerHTML = document.body.scrollTop + window.innerHeight;
}

document.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
  checkOffset();
});
```

```css
div.social-float-parent { width: 100%; height: 1000px; background: #f8f8f8; position: relative; }
div#social-float { width: 200px; position: fixed; bottom: 10px; background: #777; }
div#footer { width: 100%; height: 200px; background: #eee; }
```

```html
<div class="social-float-parent">
    <div id="social-float">
        float...
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Can now be accomplished with `position: sticky`.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: linen;
  margin: 0;
}


body,
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main,
section {
  flex: 1;
}

main {
  min-height: 200vh;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: lightcoral;
  padding: 1rem;
}

p {
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

footer {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 15rem 1rem;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <div class="sticky">
      <h2>I am sticky<h2>
    </div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>

  <p>Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique sem. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa. Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum. Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod in, nibh. Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. </p>

  <p>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nam nec ante. Sed lacinia, urna non tincidunt mattis, tortor neque adipiscing diam, a cursus ipsum ante quis turpis. Nulla facilisi. Ut fringilla. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc feugiat mi a tellus consequat imperdiet. Vestibulum sapien. Proin quam. Etiam ultrices. Suspendisse in justo eu magna luctus suscipit. Sed lectus. Integer euismod lacus luctus magna. Quisque cursus, metus vitae pharetra auctor, sem massa mattis sem, at interdum magna augue eget diam. </p>

  <p>Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi lacinia molestie dui. Praesent blandit dolor. Sed non quam. In vel mi sit amet augue congue elementum. Morbi in ipsum sit amet pede facilisis laoreet. Donec lacus nunc, viverra nec, blandit vel, egestas et, augue. Vestibulum tincidunt malesuada tellus. Ut ultrices ultrices enim. Curabitur sit amet mauris. Morbi in dui quis est pulvinar ullamcorper. Nulla facilisi. Integer lacinia sollicitudin massa. </p>

  <p>Cras metus. Sed aliquet risus a tortor. Integer id quam. Morbi mi. Quisque nisl felis, venenatis tristique, dignissim in, ultrices sit amet, augue. Proin sodales libero eget ante. Nulla quam. Aenean laoreet. Vestibulum nisi lectus, commodo ac, facilisis ac, ultricies eu, pede. Ut orci risus, accumsan porttitor, cursus quis, aliquet eget, justo. Sed pretium blandit orci. Ut eu diam at pede suscipit sodales. Aenean lectus elit, fermentum non, convallis id, sagittis at, neque. Nullam mauris orci, aliquet et, iaculis et, viverra vitae, ligula. </p>
  </section>
  <footer>
    <h2>I am a footer<h2>
  </footer>
</main>
```

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this same issue recently, posted the my solution also here:
[Preventing element from displaying on top of footer when using position:fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805404/preventing-element-from-displaying-on-top-of-footer-when-using-positionfixed)

You can achieve a solution leveraging the `position` property of the element with jQuery, switching between the default value (`static` for `divs`), `fixed` and `absolute`.
You will also need a container element for your fixed element. Finally, in order to prevent the fixed element to go over the footer, this container element can't be the parent of the footer.

The javascript part involves calculating the distance in pixels between your fixed element and the top of the document, and comparing it with the current vertical position of the scrollbar relatively to the window object (i.e. the number of pixels above that are hidden from the visible area of the page) every time the user scrolls the page.
When, on scrolling down, the fixed element is about to disappear above, we change its position to fixed and stick on top of the page.

This causes the fixed element to go over the footer when we scroll to the bottom, especially if the browser window is small.
Therefore, we will calculate the distance in pixels of the footer from the top of the document and compare it with the height of the fixed element plus the vertical position of the scrollbar: when the fixed element is about to go over the footer, we will change its position to absolute and stick at the bottom, just over the footer.

Here's a generic example.

The HTML structure:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="leftcolumn">
        <div class="fixed-element">
            This is fixed 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightcolumn">Main content here</div>
    <div id="footer"> The footer </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#leftcolumn {
    position: relative;
}
.fixed-element {
    width: 180px;
}
.fixed-element.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
}
.fixed-element.bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 356px; /* Height of the footer element, plus some extra pixels if needed */
}
```

The JS:

```
// Position of fixed element from top of the document
var fixedElementOffset = $('.fixed-element').offset().top;
// Position of footer element from top of the document.
// You can add extra distance from the bottom if needed,
// must match with the bottom property in CSS
var footerOffset = $('#footer').offset().top - 36;

var fixedElementHeight = $('.fixed-element').height(); 

// Check every time the user scrolls
$(window).scroll(function (event) {

    // Y position of the vertical scrollbar
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    if ( y >= fixedElementOffset && ( y + fixedElementHeight ) < footerOffset ) {
        $('.fixed-element').addClass('fixed');
        $('.fixed-element').removeClass('bottom');          
    }
    else if ( y >= fixedElementOffset && ( y + fixedElementHeight ) >= footerOffset ) {
        $('.fixed-element').removeClass('fixed');           
        $('.fixed-element').addClass('bottom');
    }
    else {
        $('.fixed-element').removeClass('fixed bottom');
    }

 });
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(window).scroll(() => {
    const footerToTop = $('.your-footer').position().top;
    const scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
    const difference = scrollTop - footerToTop;
    const bottomValue = scrollTop > footerToTop ? difference : 0;
    $('.your-fixed-element').css('bottom', bottomValue);
});
```

Comment: Code is always good, but it also helps to add some brief comments/explanation about how this addresses the original question.

Comment: @Ali Klein instead of setting value 0, if you give inherit property to the bottom value it will be helpful. i.e. const bottomValue = scrollTop > footerToTop ? difference : "inherit";

Answer (score 3):

I've made some changes to the second most popular answer as i found this worked better for me. The changes use window.innerHeight as it is more dynamic than adding your own height for the nav (above used + 570). this allows the code to work on mobile, tablet and desktop dynamicly.

```
$(window).scroll(() => {
            //Distance from top fo document to top of footer
            topOfFooter = $('#footer').position().top;
             // Distance user has scrolled from top + windows inner height
             scrollDistanceFromTopOfDoc = $(document).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight;
             // Difference between the two.
             scrollDistanceFromTopOfFooter = scrollDistanceFromTopOfDoc - topOfFooter; 
            // If user has scrolled further than footer,
              if (scrollDistanceFromTopOfDoc > topOfFooter) {
                // add margin-bottom so button stays above footer.
                $('#floating-button').css('margin-bottom',  0 + scrollDistanceFromTopOfFooter);
              } else  {
                // remove margin-bottom so button goes back to the bottom of the page
                $('#floating-button').css('margin-bottom', 0);
              }
            });
```

Comment: Instead of modifying the margins, in my if statement I used some JavaScript to change the element's position (instead of "fixed"). ---> document.getElementById('elementId').style.position = "absolute";

Comment: @young sir x This solution is PERFECT! I have a zillion tabs open trying solutions, and yours worked the best to make my announcement bar stop above the footer 

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me -

HTML -

```
<div id="sideNote" class="col-sm-3" style="float:right;">

</div> 
<div class="footer-wrap">
        <div id="footer-div">
        </div>      
</div>
```

CSS -

```
#sideNote{right:0; margin-top:10px; position:fixed; bottom:0; margin-bottom:5px;}

#footer-div{margin:0 auto; text-align:center; min-height:300px; margin-top:100px; padding:100px 50px;}
```

JQuery -

```
function isVisible(elment) {
    var vpH = $(window).height(), // Viewport Height
        st = $(window).scrollTop(), // Scroll Top
        y = $(elment).offset().top;

    return y <= (vpH + st);
}

function setSideNotePos(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if (isVisible($('.footer-wrap'))) {
            $('#sideNote').css('position','absolute');
            $('#sideNote').css('top',$('.footer-wrap').offset().top - $('#sideNote').outerHeight() - 100);
        } else {
            $('#sideNote').css('position','fixed');
            $('#sideNote').css('top','auto');
        }
    });
}
```

Now call this function like this -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setSideNotePos();
});
```

PS - The Jquery functions are copied from an answer to another similar question on stackoverflow, but it wasn't working for me fully. So I modified it to these functions, as they are shown here. I think the position etc attributes to your divs will depend on how the divs are structured, who their parents and siblings are.

The above function works when both sideNote and footer-wraps are direct siblings.

Answer (score 1):

@Lionel Paulus' pure JS answer worked for me best. The only thing I had an issue with, was the innerHTML counter was overriding my element. Works perfect when I removed this:

```
socialFloat.innerHTML = document.body.scrollTop + window.innerHeight;
```

```js
var socialFloat = document.querySelector('#social-float');
var footer = document.querySelector('#footer');

function checkOffset() {
  function getRectTop(el){
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    return rect.top;
  }
  
  if((getRectTop(socialFloat) + document.body.scrollTop) + socialFloat.offsetHeight >= (getRectTop(footer) + document.body.scrollTop) - 10)
    socialFloat.style.position = 'absolute';
  if(document.body.scrollTop + window.innerHeight < (getRectTop(footer) + document.body.scrollTop))
    socialFloat.style.position = 'fixed'; // restore when you scroll up
  
}

document.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
  checkOffset();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I went with a modification of @user1097431 's answer:

```
function menuPosition(){
// distance from top of footer to top of document
var footertotop = ($('.footer').position().top);
// distance user has scrolled from top, adjusted to take in height of bar (42 pixels inc. padding)
var scrolltop = $(document).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight;
// difference between the two
var difference = scrolltop-footertotop;

// if user has scrolled further than footer,
// pull sidebar up using a negative margin
if (scrolltop > footertotop) {
    $('#categories-wrapper').css({
       'bottom' : difference
   });
}else{
    $('#categories-wrapper').css({
       'bottom' : 0
   });
 };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can now use

```
#myObject{
  position:sticky;
}
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: No IE 11 support.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on stopping the adbanner at a certain point before footer. And played with the code I found above.

Worked for me (banner disappears right before footer and reappears on scroll to top):

```
<style>
#leftsidebanner {width:300px;height:600px;position: fixed; padding: 0;top:288px;right:5%;display: block;background-color: aqua}
</style>

<div id="leftsidebanner">
</div>


<script>

    $.fn.followTo = function (pos) {
    var stickyAd = $(this),
    theWindow = $(window);
    $(window).scroll(function (e) {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > pos) {
        stickyAd.css({'position': 'absolute','bottom': pos});
      } else {
        stickyAd.css({'position': 'fixed','top': '100'});
      }
    });
  };
  $('#leftsidebanner').followTo(2268);


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your elements are glitching this is probably because when you change the position to `relative` the Y position of the footer increases which tries to send the item back to `fixed` which creates a loop. You can avoid this by setting two different cases when scrolling up and down. You don't even need to reference the fixed element, just the footer, and window size.

```js
const footer = document.querySelector('footer');
document.addEventListener("scroll", checkScroll);

let prevY = window.scrollY + window.innerHeight;
function checkScroll() {
  let footerTop = getRectTop(footer) + window.scrollY;
  let windowBottomY = window.scrollY + window.innerHeight;
  if (prevY < windowBottomY) {  // Scroll Down
    if (windowBottomY > footerTop)
      setScrolledToFooter(true) // using React state. Change class or change style in JS.
  } else { // Scroll Up
    if (windowBottomY <= footerTop)
      setScrolledToFooter(false)
  }
  prevY = windowBottomY
};

function getRectTop(el) {
  var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  return rect.top;
}
```

and the position of the element in the style object as follows:

```js
position: scrolledToFooter ? 'relative' : 'fixed'
```

Answer (score -1):

A pure css solution

```
<div id="outer-container">
    <div id="scrollable">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam in vulputate turpis. Curabitur a consectetur libero. Nulla ac velit nibh, ac lacinia nulla. In sed urna sit amet mauris vulputate viverra et et eros. Pellentesque laoreet est et neque euismod a bibendum velit laoreet. Nam gravida lectus nec purus porttitor porta. Vivamus tempor tempus auctor. Nam quis porttitor ligula. Vestibulum rutrum fermentum ligula eget luctus. Sed convallis iaculis lorem non adipiscing. Sed in egestas lectus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nunc dictum, lacus quis venenatis ultricies, turpis lorem bibendum dui, quis bibendum lacus ante commodo urna. Fusce ut sem mi, nec molestie tortor. Mauris eu leo diam. Nullam adipiscing, tortor eleifend pellentesque gravida, erat tellus vulputate orci, quis accumsan orci ipsum sed justo. Proin massa massa, pellentesque non tristique non, tristique vel dui. Vestibulum at metus at neque malesuada porta et vitae lectus.
    </div>
    <button id="social-float">The button</button>
</div>
<div>
Footer
</div>
</div>
```

And css here

```
#outer-container {
    position: relative;
}

#scrollable {
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

#social-float {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```