# How to unstick a floating div at the bottom when footer tag is detected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating an effect in my page. I have a news page and what I want is  if the user scroll the page there will be a floating div with a button at the bottom of the screen. It should stick at the bottom of the screen. But it will stick until it hasn't reached the footer content. I don't know how to do this. Can you help me with this?

Here's a bit of my codes:

HTML:

```
<header>Header Goes Here</header>
<div class="container">
    <div class="news">
       <p>Very long content here...</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="floating_content">
    <button>Next Page</button>
</div>
<footer>Footer Here</footer>
```

CSS:

```
header { 
    height: 50px; 
    background: #ccc; 
    color: #fff; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: verdana;
    text-align: center;
}

.news { padding: 10px }

.floating_content {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ccc;
}
footer {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        $(".floating_content").removeAttr('style');
        //$(".fix_content").css('margin-bottom':'174px');
    } else {
        $(".floating_content").css({'position':'fixed','bottom':'0','width':'100%','z-index':'99'});
    }
});
```

Here's my fiddle:[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rochellecanale/09oj299u/9/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Float a div at the bottom right corner, but not inside footer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18455453/float-a-div-at-the-bottom-right-corner-but-not-inside-footer)

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       $(".floating_content").show();
   }
});
```

UPDATED2:

I'm trying to set and change the position in floating-content into `relative` as in:

```
.floating_content {
    display: none;
    position:relative; //here
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Updated Jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/alicera/09oj299u/4/)

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work. I want place the floating div in the top of the footer. If the footer is displayed in the browser.

Comment: Sorry it doesnt what I want. What I want is the floating div will be hide first. Then if the user scroll the page the floating div will be displayed at the bottom of the browser not by the page itself. Then when scrolling the floating div is stick at the bottom of the browser then until it reaches the top part of the footer then it will stay at the top of the footer. Then if the user scroll up the page the floating div will be at the bottom of the page again.