# When changing div to position absolute it jumps to original position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently trying to make a floating table of the right hand side of the screen, while having other content on the left.

The left and right columns are separated using bootstrap `class="col-md-6`.

making the table float is easy however i want it to stop floating at the bottom of the left hand div.

I followed this tutorial https://stackoverflow.com/a/8653109/9364403

and my floating div does change to `position:absolute;` when it reaches the bottom of the div.

However when the position is set to absolute, the table goes back to the position in the top of the div and does not stay at the bottom. When i scroll back up a little bit the table goes back to floating.

How can i ensure that the flaoting div does not jump back up like the jsfiddle showing the comment link above? (http://jsfiddle.net/Kkv7X/)

current html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="">

    <div class="col-md-6">
    Content for the left hand column
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6" style="position:relative;">
      <div class="positionfixed" id="fixedcard">
        <table class="table" id="recipetable">
          <tr class="tablerow">
            <th class="tableheader" style="width:45%;">header 1</th>
            <th class="tableheader" style="width:25%;">header 2</th>
            <th class="tableheader" style="width:30%;">header 3</th>
            <th class="tableheader" style="width:30%;">header 4</th>
          </tr>
          <tr class="tablerow">
            <td>row 1</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="tablerow">
            <td>row 2</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="tablerow">
            <td>row 3</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="tablerow">
            <td>row 4</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="tablerow" id="TableTotalRow">
            <td>row 5</td>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
            <td ></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<div id="stop">
</div>
```

current js:

```
function checkOffset() {
    if($('#fixedcard').offset().top + $('#fixedcard').height() >= $('#stop').offset().top - 10){
      $('#fixedcard').css('position', 'absolute');
    }
    if($(document).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight < $('#stop').offset().top){
      $('#fixedcard').css('position', 'fixed'); // restore when you scroll up
    }
  }
  $(document).scroll(function() {
    checkOffset();
  });
```

current css:

```
 .positionfixed{
    position: fixed;
  }
```

I made a jsFiddle of what my code is currently doing here: https://jsfiddle.net/fjfkbrtn/12/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change to `absolute` just set the `bottom` CSS property to 0px and change it back when the position goes back to `fixed`, like so:

```
function checkOffset() {
  if ($('#fixedcard').offset().top + $('#fixedcard').height() >= $('#stop').offset().top - 10) {
    $('#fixedcard').css('position', 'absolute');
    $('#fixedcard').css('bottom', '0px'); // ADD THIS
  }
  if ($(document).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight < $('#stop').offset().top) {
    $('#fixedcard').css('position', 'fixed'); 
     $('#fixedcard').css('bottom', 'initial'); // AND THIS 
  }
}
$(document).scroll(function() {
  checkOffset();
});
```

Comment: I spent a couple hours on this, and i almost had it. i tried to set bottom to 0px but i never changed it back to initial. Thanks for the answer!