# How to stop fixed position scrolling at footer

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've done plenty of research into this and I can't seem to figure out why this isn't working for me.

I have two div elements. One of these divs has `position: fixed` to keep it in the window at all times.

Once the div hits the footer, it should remove the fixed scrolling and stick to the top of the footer. I've tried using the code found in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653025/stop-fixed-position-at-footer), but the div just snaps back up to the top of the page when it reaches the footer.

Here's a fiddle for an example:

```js
$(document).scroll(function (){
  if($('.userInfo').offset().top + $('.userInfo').height() >= $('footer').offset().top - 10){
    $('.userInfo').css('position', 'absolute');
  }
        
  if($(document).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight < $('footer').offset().top){
    $('.userInfo').css('position', 'fixed');
  } 
});
```

```css
.profileMain{
    display: flex;
}

.userInfoContainer{
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.userInfo{
    background: red;
    width: 50%;
    position: fixed;
}

.userContent{
    background: blue;
    width: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 10em;
}

footer{
  background: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class = "profileMain">
  <div class = "userInfoContainer">
    <div class = "userInfo">f</div>
  </div>
  <div class = "userContent">f</div>
</div>

<footer></footer>
```

Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't see where you are setting the top position when you swap to position:fixed.

Its going to default to the top of the page.

To fix, in your footer css, set the top and left position where you need them to be.

Comment: @Korgrue I'm not sure what you mean. Is this not a problem with the jQuery code? I've tried setting `bottom: 0` when it hits the footer, but that didn't do anything either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to do the opposite of the example you provided ( sticking the div to the top and not to bottom ) , remove the `window.innerHeight` from the second `if` and compare the scroll + the element's height with `offset` of the footer, and use `top` and `bottom` positionning to place the div where you want,

this should do the trick :

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
  if ($('.userInfo').offset().top + $('.userInfo').height() >= $('footer').offset().top - 10)
    $('.userInfo').css({
      'position': 'absolute',
      'bottom': 0,
      'top': 'auto'
    });

  if ($(document).scrollTop() + $('.userInfo').height() < $('footer').offset().top)
    $('.userInfo').css({
      'position': 'fixed',
      'top': 0,
      'bottom': 'auto'
    }); // restore when you scroll up
});
```

here's a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/93144/

Comment: I apologize, I missed a key point in my question. Once the div hits the footer, I want to remove the fixed positioning and have it stick to the top of the footer. I've edited the question to include this.

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/93144/ ? if it is i will update the answer

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for. Thank you. Will select as correct answer once updated

Comment: you got it bro ;)

Comment: But these is a problem in this code, you need to execute the first if condition after the second one, interchange each other