# Dynamic bottom value based on element position in browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am attempting to adapt [this JS solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39365673/19798024) to keep a floating element above the footer of my site.

The adaption I am attempting is instead of changing the element position to absolute, I would have a dynamic bottom px value based on the position of the top of the footer, relevant to the client window.

```
function checkOffset() {

  var onlineFloat = document.querySelector('#online-ceo');
  var footer = document.querySelector('.site-footer');

  function getRectTop(el){
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    return rect.top;
  }
    
  if((getRectTop(onlineFloat) + document.body.scrollTop) + onlineFloat.offsetHeight >= (getRectTop(footer) + document.body.scrollTop) - 20)
        var newBottom = ((getRectTop(footer) + document.body.scrollTop) - 40).toString().concat('px');
    onlineFloat.style.bottom = newBottom;

  if(document.body.scrollTop + window.innerHeight < (getRectTop(footer) + document.body.scrollTop))
    onlineFloat.style.bottom = '20px';// restore when you scroll up
    
}

document.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
  checkOffset();
});
```

The output of newBottom is currently a px value which changes on scroll, however, I am having issues setting this position to the element.

Where am I going wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your approach (changing the bottom property), you can just calculate where the "float" should be if the footer's top position is in view (as in window.innerHeight) on scroll.

```js
        function checkOffset() {
            var onlineFloat = document.querySelector('#online-ceo');
            var footer = document.querySelector('.site-footer');

            function getRectTop(el) {
                var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
                return rect.top;
            }
            var newBottom = 10 + (getRectTop(footer) < window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight - getRectTop(footer) : 0) + 'px';

            onlineFloat.style.bottom = newBottom;
        }

        document.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
            checkOffset();
        });
```